# First Java Program: Random data in my Array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, boolean

Problem: Write a program that reads a list of real numbers.  After the program ends it should print out only the unique numbers.  That is, only numbers that appear once in the list.  If there are more than 50 unique numbers on the list, then you should only print the first 50.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Hmwk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
    int n = 0;
    final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
    double[] numbersArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
    while (input.hasNextDouble() && n<MAX_SIZE){
        double in = input.nextDouble();
        if (inList(in,numbersArray))
            numbersArray[n]=in;
            n++;

    }
    printReport(numbersArray);
}


public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
    for (double i : list)
        {
            if (i == number){
                return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}


public static void printReport(double[] list)
{
    System.out.println("The unique numbers were");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

}


}
```

input.txt file=

```
5.0 6.0 7.0 8.9 3.0 2.0 8.9 8.9 9.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0
```

results-
    The unique numbers were
    [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.9, 3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,             0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

No idea where I'm going wrong here, I think its my inlist method? Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bracket for `IF` condition

```
if (inList(in,numbersArray))
{
            numbersArray[n]=in;
            n++;
}
```

Comment: You should always uses braces like that even for one liners.

Comment: @evanchooly yes sir.It must be habbit

Comment: I'm still not getting the correct data.. It's adding numbers into the array that there are two of in the text file. No idea whats going on

Comment: @user102817 i run on my system and after this change it is working fine.I guess u r having concern y many values are 0? the answer is all the values of array of type double is initialized with default value and default value of double is 0.0

Comment: I'm still not sure where im going wrong. im using the data 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 0 and am getting... The unique numbers were
[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0] in return. Obviously 8 and 9 shouldn't be there since they aren't the only 8 or 9 in the list.

Comment: you dnt add such facility tht 8 and 9 will not be in the list.You need to update the code

Answer (score 1):

Your if needs braces

```
if (inList(in,numbersArray)){
            numbersArray[n]=in;
            n++;
}
```

or  do this

```
if (inList(in,numbersArray))
                numbersArray[n++]=in;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `n` whether the number is already in the list or not. What you've written is (re-indented for clarity):

```
if (inList(in,numbersArray))
            numbersArray[n]=in;
n++;
```

But it should be:

```
if (inList(in,numbersArray)) {
            numbersArray[n]=in;
            n++;
}
```

Then when you're done, truncate the list to be `n` elements long.

Comment: How would I go about truncating it?